# Bit shift in F#

Tags: f#, bit-shift

I am new to F# and I do not understand how a bit shift works in F#.

I tried the command below in fsi.

```
> 4
- |>((<<<) 1uy);;
```

The screen shot is as below.

[image]

Why is this result 16uy but not 8uy?

Even confused me more when I tried the command below because the result is 48uy...

```
> 4
- |>((<<<) 3uy);;
```

Would you somebody describe me how this works?

Comment: Please attempt to paste the code as text instead of linking an image. We can help with the formatting if needed.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I did not know how to copy the code from fsi screen. It will be grateful if you could help me the formatting.

Comment: Thank you for the formatting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/symbol-and-operator-reference/bitwise-operators):

> Bitwise left-shift operator. **The result is the first operand with bits shifted left by the number of bits in the second operand.** Bits shifted off the most significant position are not rotated into the least significant position. The least significant bits are padded with zeros. The type of the second argument is int32.

It's been a while since I've used F#, but assuming its operator prefixing works like Haskell's then the way you've used it:

```
4 |> ((<<<) 1uy)
```

will apply 1 as the left-hand argument, and 4 as the right-hand argument:

```
1 <<< 4
```

Which will be `16`.

To get it to equal `8`, try removing the parentheses around the operator itself (meaning it won't be prefixed but instead just partially applied with the right-hand argument) to get:

```
4 |> (<<< 1uy)
```

and that should give you `8`, assuming it's valid F# syntax.